# How add values to child form by parent ID?

Tags: python, django

This is my model

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Phone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Osoba, editable=False, related_name='phone', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and i want to add phone to current User selected by ID and display it on site

i have tried that

```
def create_phone(request, id):

    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    form = PhoneForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)

    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()
        return redirect('list_users')

    return render(request, 'index-phone.html', {'form': form})
```

But it doesnt work, when i click button, its not creating new Phone

My urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', list_users, name='list_users'),
    path('new', create_user, name='create_user'),
    path('/<int:id>/update', update_user, name='update_user'),
    path('/<int:id>/delete', delete_user, name='delete_user'),
    path('/<int:id>/', create_phone, name='create_phone')

]
```

Comment: Do you make a POST request?

Comment: Yes <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the content of your PhoneForm class, but I would guess that is a form to create and edit a Phone object. When instantiating a new PhoneForm the instance parameter should either be an existing Phone instance, or None.

You should set the user of the Phone instance another way, either by making it a field on the PhoneForm, or by manually setting the user.

This would be correct:

```
def create_phone(request, id):

    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    form = PhoneForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

    # Setting commit to False does not save the object to the database yet.
    # We do this because we still want to edit the object.
    phone = form.save(commit=False)
    phone.user = user
    phone.save()
    return redirect('list_users')

return render(request, 'index-phone.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: What about this? NOT NULL constraint failed: phonebookapp_phone.user_id. I just want to create User, but after this created user i could click on edit and insert phone to him

Comment: You can try to instantiate the phone object before saving the form:
...
`phone = Phone(user = user)

form.instance = phone

form.save()`
...

Comment: So it works, but do u know why when i enter value from POST , It creating object, but without values that i entered?